# Can we invoke Sitecore GraphQL as API using Postman

Tags: graphql

We have a requirement to get Sitecore items as invokable API using postman. Now postman is started supporting GraphQL. But when we try to invoke the Sitecore GraphQL I'm getting the error:

> URL: https://domain/api/appname/ui?sc_apikey={key}

> [HttpException]: A public action method 'ui' was not found on controller 'Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.Mvc.GraphQLController'.
> at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)

Can anyone suggest a way to expose using postman? I know Sitecore provides a nice GraphQL UI to browse through.

Comment: Can you please share the URL you're requesting? It seems you're using playground URL (remove "/ui" from the URL) and try again. Also, make sure you created an API key and you're passing it (sc_apikey param)

Comment: Yeah. I was using "ui" in the URL. when I removed it started working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I remove the 'ui' in the sample URL it started working. Able to invoke the Sitecore Graphql using postman.

> URL: https://domain/api/appname/**ui**?sc_apikey={key}

after removing 'ui' from URL

> URL: https://domain/api/appname?sc_apikey={key}